# Asymptotic distribution of the average of $p$ sample-percentile

Tags: probability, asymptotics, order-statistics, quantiles

Here is a question which seems to be intuitively simple, yet I am not able to 
show it rigorously.

Any help, whether it is carrying out my attempt or to suggest any other approach  - would be greatly appreciated.

Also, please, see the note on a similar question.

---

---

**The problem**

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ iid samples drawn from uniform distribution $X_i \sim U[0,1]$. **What is the asymptotic distribution of *sum* of the top $0<p<1$ sample percentile?**

That is, what is the asymptotic distribution of $S_p(n)$, where

$$
S_p(n) := \frac{1}{p\cdot n}\sum_{i = p \cdot n}^n X_{(i)}\,.
$$

(with $X_{(i)}$ is the *i*-th order statistic. Additionally, to spare the clutter in the notation, I have ignored rounding to the integer in the summation over index $i= \lfloor p \cdot n \rfloor$)

Intuitively, I would argue that when $n$ grows high the  top $p$ percentile is  uniformly distributed on the interval $[p ,1]$ therefor, the sum is asymptotically equivalent to the sum of uniform random samples drawn from $U[p, 1]$.
Which leads to

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_p(n) - \mathbb{E}S_p(n)}{\sqrt{\text{var}(S_p(n))}}\right) = 
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_p(n) - \frac{(p+1)}{2}}{\frac{(1-p)}{\sqrt{12}}}\right)
\to N(0, 1)\,. $$

---

**Note:**

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161145/distribution-of-sum-of-order-statistics), I was not sure whether to post a comment there or ask a new question, eventually I did both and put a reference in both places.

Additionally, since one can always go from general distribution to uniform one by inverse cdf transform $F^{-1}(x)$, what I ask  is a in a more general setting.

---

---

**Outline of my Attempt to solve**.

(As already noted, this is in the spirit of the answer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161145/distribution-of-sum-of-order-statistics))

$\mathbf{1)}$ Look at the random vector
$$
(y, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{n}) := \left(\sum_{j=m}^n X_{(j)}, X_{(m+1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}\right)\,.
$$
$\mathbf{2)}$ Find the joint distribution of the vector from $\mathbf{1)}$. By change of variable for distribution of  $$\left(X_{(m)}, X_{(m+1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}\right)\,.$$

$\mathbf{3)}$ Integrate out $x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n$ to get distribution for $\sum_{j=m}^n X_{(j)}$. **(Stuck here)**

$\mathbf{4)}$ See if this helps to find the asymptotic distribution. (**Actually, not sure if the previous step really helps here**)

---

---

**Details**

In general, the joint probability density of order statistics of iid samples drawn form continuous distribution $F(x)$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161145/distribution-of-sum-of-order-statistics)):
$$
f(x_m ,\ldots, x_n)  = n! f(x_n) \cdots f(x_{m})\frac{F(x_m)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\mathbb{I}\{0 <x_m<x_{m+1}< \cdots< x_n\}\,,
$$

where $\mathbb{I}\{A\}$ is indicator of the set $A$.

For the uniform distribution the above yields
$$
f(x_m ,\ldots, x_n)  = n! \frac{(x_m)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\mathbb{I}\{0 <x_m<x_{m+1}< \cdots< x_n\}\,.
$$

Let change of variables
$$
\tau: \left(X_{(m)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}\right) \to \left(\underbrace{\sum_{j=m}^n X_{(j)}}_{Y}, X_{(m+1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}\right)\,.
$$
$$
\tau^{-1}(Y, X_{(m+1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}) \to \left(Y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n X_{(j)}\,, X_{(m+1)}\,, \ldots\,, X_{(n)}\right). 
$$
The determinant of the Jacobian of the inverse $\tau^{-1}$ is one. The distribution after the change of variables is 
$$
f(y, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_n) = n! \frac{(y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_{j})^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\mathbb{I}\left\{0 <y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_{j}< x_{m+1}< \cdots< x_n\right\}\,.
$$

Basically, at this point I want to be able to integrate

$$
\int \cdots \int  n! \frac{(y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_{j})^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \mathbb{I}\left\{0 <y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_{j}< x_{m+1}< \cdots< x_n\right\} dx_{m+1}\cdots dx_{n} 
$$

$$
=
\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^y dx_{m+1} \int_{\frac{y-x_{m+1}}{2}}^y dx_{m+2} \cdots \int_{\frac{y- \sum_{j=1}^kx_j}{2}}^y d{x_{k+1}} \cdots \int_{\frac{y-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_j}{2}}^y n! \frac{(y - \sum_{j=m+1}^n x_{j})^{n-m-1}}{(n-m-1)!} d{x_{n}} \,.
$$

I am stuck, can't see an easy way to disentangle the resulting integral .

Comment: For the case of exp. distribution, i.e.,  $X_i \sim \exp(1)$, one can show that $(X_{(m+1)} - X_{(m)}, \ldots, X_{(n)} - X_{(m)})| X_{m}$ is distributed as ord. statistic of $Y_i, n-m$ i.i.d samples from $exp(1)$, therefor $\frac{1}{m-n}\sum_{i=m+1}^n X_{(i)} - X_{(m)}| X_{(m)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-m} Y_i - (n-m)X_{m} |X_{m}$. At the limit $n\to \infty$,  $X_{(m}) \to F^{-1}(p)$ while $\sum_{i=1}^{n-m} Y_i$ has asymptotic normal distribution..., does this extends to the unconditioned version? Is this development only works for exponential distribution, and cannot help with uniform distribution?

Comment: For problems like this, I would suggest doing some numerical experiments before going too deep into the math. That way you have some guidance on where the math should be headed.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 thanks for pointing out.  I have also asked a similar question on exponential distribution [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232184/asymptotic-distribution-of-censored-samples-from-exp-lambda). The question with the exponential distribution is from a practice exam, but no solution is given there. So I know the other question should have  relatively straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this freely downloadable paper answers the question, [Stigler, S. M. (1969). **Linear functions of order statistics**. The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 770-788.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697587).

It adopts an indirect way to prove asymptotic normality, namely, the author constructs a sum of i.i.d. rv's that approximate a linear combination of order statistics, and then he shows that they are asymptotically equivalent. Moreover it has relevant literature references.